# Setting the 404 page without using the NodeId or Guid

Tags: umbraco8

I have a webapplication using umbraco which has a page of custom type SinglePageApplication. This content page is on the root:

```
Content
  |
  |-Portal (of Type SinglePageApplication)
```

This page has an Id (for example: 1050) and this page contains an Angular app. What I want is when a url doesn't exist and umbraco should throw the 404, it goes to this page and let Angular handle the page not found situation.

To achieve this, I have changed the error404 configuration in the umbracoSettings.config to this

```
<error404>1050</error404>
```

And this works. But soon this web application will be released to live which has a different database and the Portal page probably will have a different Id (and Guid). Obviously, the 404's which umbraco receives will not be forwarded to the right page anymore and I have to change the id manually on the live server. And I would like to prevent that.

The examples in the umbracosettings.config states I can use xpaths and I found many examples when I googled this issue but all were for umbraco 7 and as none of them seems to work for umbraco 8, I got the feeling something might have changed for this setting. Unfortunately, the documentation for umbraco 8 is quite poor currently.

What I have tried so far are:

```
    <error404>//Page[nodeName='Portal']</error404>
    <error404>//SinglePageApplication[node='Portal']</error404>
    <error404>$site//SinglePageApplication[node='Portal']</error404>
    <error404>$root//SinglePageApplication[node='Portal']</error404>
```

Perhaps I missed one but they didn't work either, all resulted in the ugly 404 page.

What is the way to forward umbraco to a content page when a 404 occured, like it works with using the NodeId but then without being bound to the nodeId or Guid of a page?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following in the web.config and then set the path variable to be whatever you like.

```
 <httpErrors>
    <error statusCode="404" path="/errors/404/" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />  
</httpErrors>
```